# MPAndroidChart Bar Shadows hides the actual bars

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using the combined chart to draw stacked bars and a line chart on top of it.
When I set the bar shadow to true, some of the bars are hidden.
This is the code I have with bar shadow set to true.

```
public void setupChart(CombinedChart combinedChart)
{

    combinedChart.setDrawOrder(new CombinedChart.DrawOrder[]{CombinedChart.DrawOrder.BAR, CombinedChart.DrawOrder.LINE});
    combinedChart.setNoDataText("");
    combinedChart.setNoDataTextDescription("");
    combinedChart.setDescription(null);
    combinedChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    combinedChart.setDrawBarShadow(true);
    combinedChart.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

    XAxisValueFormatter customX=new MyXAxisValueFormatter();

    XAxis xAxis=combinedChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    xAxis.setDrawLabels(true);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setGridColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Gray));
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(customX);
    xAxis.setSpaceBetweenLabels(2);

    YAxisValueFormatter customY=new MyYAxisValueFormatter();

    YAxis leftAxis=combinedChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setLabelCount(4, false);
    leftAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    leftAxis.setValueFormatter(customY);
    leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
    leftAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);

    YAxis rightAxis=combinedChart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setEnabled(false);

    combinedChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
}
```

And I get the following chart

[image]

The same code with bar shadow set to false

```
combinedChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
```

produces the following chart with the bars right as expected.

[image]

Am i doing anything out of order here ?

If it's a bug which I hope not, can i achieve the bar shadows using the grid lines ?

Great library nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Phil. I got a response thru GitHub. The fix should be out in the next release I guess. But this is the method that needed to be updated in the BarChartRenderer class.

It basically draws the shadows before the actual bars are drawn

```
protected void drawDataSet(Canvas c, IBarDataSet dataSet, int index) {

    Transformer trans = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.getAxisDependency());

    mShadowPaint.setColor(dataSet.getBarShadowColor());

    float phaseX = mAnimator.getPhaseX();
    float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();

    // initialize the buffer
    BarBuffer buffer = mBarBuffers[index];
    buffer.setPhases(phaseX, phaseY);
    buffer.setBarSpace(dataSet.getBarSpace());
    buffer.setDataSet(index);
    buffer.setInverted(mChart.isInverted(dataSet.getAxisDependency()));

    buffer.feed(dataSet);

    trans.pointValuesToPixel(buffer.buffer);

    // draw the bar shadow before the values
    if (mChart.isDrawBarShadowEnabled()) {

        for (int j = 0; j < buffer.size(); j += 4) {

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(buffer.buffer[j + 2]))
                continue;

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(buffer.buffer[j]))
                break;

            c.drawRect(buffer.buffer[j], mViewPortHandler.contentTop(),
                    buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                    mViewPortHandler.contentBottom(), mShadowPaint);
        }
    }

    // if multiple colors
    if (dataSet.getColors().size() > 1) {

        for (int j = 0; j < buffer.size(); j += 4) {

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(buffer.buffer[j + 2]))
                continue;

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(buffer.buffer[j]))
                break;

            // Set the color for the currently drawn value. If the index
            // is
            // out of bounds, reuse colors.
            mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor(j / 4));
            c.drawRect(buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                    buffer.buffer[j + 3], mRenderPaint);
        }
    } else {

        mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor());

        for (int j = 0; j < buffer.size(); j += 4) {

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(buffer.buffer[j + 2]))
                continue;

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(buffer.buffer[j]))
                break;

            c.drawRect(buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                    buffer.buffer[j + 3], mRenderPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.